# auditctl: Error - nested rule files not supported

Tags: audit, auditd

I'm trying to list the rules in a rules file using `auditctl`, whenever I do: `auditctl -R audit.rules -l`; I receive the error `Error - nested rule files not supported`. I've gone so far as to empty the rules file I'm trying to load, but I still get this! Is it loading from somewhere else?

When I do `auditctl -l` I get: `No rules, just right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

`auditctl -R file` is meant to be run by itself to load the auditctl rules in.

Then you can `auditctl -l` and that will list all the rules you just defined.